# Comment not eligible for voting or flagging

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-flags

For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143045/commenting-on-a-thread?noredirect=1 (10K only).
If you would try to vote on a comment you would get this dialog:

[image: popup 1]

---

#### If you try to flag it you get this dialog:

[image: flag popup]

### What?

Did the system not just tell me that was not possible?

Curious.

So I tried it. I typed in some random info into the other tab.

Clicked on `Flag Comment` and lo and behold -- I get the same dialog as if I had voted.

Shouldn't **just** the first dialog come up in this instance?

Why give people false hope into thinking they can flag by letting them put in all the information and then showing the dialog?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that migrated questions are implicitly locked, but there's no way to see that unless you look in the revision history.

Comment: @AnnaLear no way to see what? the link is on the migrated question.

Comment: It's a bit bizarre that they can't even be flagged.  Questions can easily be migrated with offensive/other comments left behind.

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama I'm talking about seeing the fact that a migrated question is locked. That is, Migrated = Locked = No voting or anything else possible on it.

Comment: @AnnaLear hmmm well I guess that is true as well.

Comment: @AnnaLear and you cannot even get to revision history because there is no link.... (here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8143045/revisions)

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama I see the link to revisions on the original question. Click "history" (or "timeline", if you prefer that view).

Comment: @AnnaLear I see **no** history or timeline link.

Comment: @AManAPlanACanalPanama Nevermind, I'm an idiot who can't keep [her userscripts straight](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a). You're right, there's no easily accessible link unless you know the URL.

Comment: @MatthewRead I don't see why flagging for comments *after* migration is a must - flagging them now is useless(the comments are already on the destination site) plus the migration stubs are autodeleted