# Can we improve the UI when a comment "is not eligible for flagging or voting"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, user-interface, locked

I came across an unusual question on Meta today: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179165/should-stackoverflow-run-a-programmers-matrimonial-service-to-prevent-marriage

I went to vote up some of the comments but couldn't:

[image]

I found some other questions on the matter:

- [Comment not eligible for voting or flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112315/200868) - Anna says it's because the question is locked (in a comment)
- [this comment is not eligible for voting or flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10905/this-comment-is-not-eligible-for-voting-or-flagging) - the accepted answer says it's because the question is deleted - not the case here, another answer says the comment has been deleted - also not the case here, and a third says the comment is from the old site and can't be voted, no mention of locking
- [What kind of comment is not eligible for voting or flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73470/what-kind-of-comment-is-not-eligible-for-voting-or-flagging) again mentions locking

I believe the real reason is because of the migration: comments left before migration can't be voted on (or flagged, which I think is likely a problem) on the new site. **Is this in fact the reason? And if so, could the little red box say so?**

[image: This comment is from another site and not eligible for voting or flagging]

> This comment is from another site and not eligible for voting or flagging

Would save a moment of confusion, right?

Comment: Do I Notice MS Paint here?

Comment: Paint Shop Pro 4.14, copyright 1997. If it ain't broke, don't upgrade :-)

Comment: Anyone know why I don't see a list of Linked Questions on the side of this question when there are links to 4 questions in it? I only see the Related list.

Comment: I don't think comments from migrations are protected in any way, I suspect what happened is that you tried to vote after the question was closed. A migrated question that is closed reverses the migration and locks the question (which you can't see as the migration and close banners occupy all notice slots).

Comment: Thats weird. I changed one of the links and now all of them show up in the linked posts.

Comment: It's not because the comments are from another site, it's because the post is locked (invisibly) when migrations are rejected. I thiiiink it already tells you when comments aren't eligible for deletion by flagging, but locked comments could definitely use a better error message.

Comment: This error also happens when you're trying to remove your own comment from the proposal which is in *Commitment* phase. So the message should be far more general than than to include invalid votes and removal operations.